# MySQL: updating and reading the same row frequently

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I made an app in which polls are sent to users via push notifications, and they have a short time to answer. We now have a deal with a news agency, and chances are that up to 100 000 people will answer to the polls sent by this company in a short period of time (5 minutes for example).

I have a MySQL database stored on Amazon RDS. Polls are stored in an innodb table:

```
CREATE TABLE `polls` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `categoryId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `question` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `expiresAt` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `sentAt` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `opt1` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `opt2` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `text1` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `text2` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `special` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3284 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

When people start voting, we increment the value of opt1 or opt2 by 1. For example if someone voted for option 1:

```
UPDATE polls SET opt1=opt1 +1 WHERE id=4644";
```

How can I configure MySQL to ensure it can support this load of traffic? I tried to go through the official docs but I can not find a clear overview of the steps I should take. Obviously I can buy a better database on AWS, but I want to be sure I am not making a mistake on scalability here.

By the way, all select queries (when people just read the polls) are sent to a replicated database on AWS.

Many thanks for your help, please ask for more information if I forgot something.

Comment: There is no "THE ANSWER" for your question. Do say nothing about your traffic, and the other querys, the disk, ram etc. I see that you have only 3284 records in the table. This is not much.

Comment: @BerndBuffen I think you don't understand the problem, there are only 3284 polls, but the number of people reading them is much, much higher.

Comment: sorry, but one of the parameter for the speed is the size (rows) of a table. If you have much read you can enable the query cache to speed up the result. and if you can change your schema then separate the to text fields in a other table with the same primary key, so your writes are faster. If this system running ?

Comment: you can also call to check your configuration and post the results later. My phone number is in my profile

Comment: Yes I have a cache on my webservice for the reads. However I am worried about the update operations. I read that innodb locks a row when it is updating it, so I am afraid that the multiple update operations on the same poll (=row) will lock each other and timeout.

Thank you for your advice, I will seperate the two text fields.

Comment: I would suggest looking into DynamoDB atomic counters and provisioned throughput as an alternative to using MySQL. Another alternative would be to send all the updates to an SQS queue, and process them slowly over time. That would allow SQS to absorb any sudden surges in traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd create a separate table for the poll results in order to have rows has short as possible for the update statement to work with.

```
CREATE TABLE `pollResults` (
  `poolId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `opt1` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `opt2` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`poolId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3284 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

In your polls table, I would put all the text column at the end of the table, but this might not be a big deal.

Comment: Sorry, put the text fields in a separate table, so the table is smaler and innodb hold more records in the buffer. MyISAM is not usable for you. MyISAM has a TABLE LOCK on write. If one writes to the table nobody else can read or write

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  I will make the poll table smaller. I will change my replicated database to myISAM since there are no updates on it. I didn't know CHAR is faster than VARCHAR, I will do that as well.

Comment: MyISAM is a suggestion on the replacated database, where all the select queries are done according to the question. The main table where the updates are done stays InnoDB, of course.

Comment: CHAR is faster than VARCHAR on MyISAM tables when your WHERE clause deals with the primary key, because all rows in the table file will be the same length. In all other cases it won't help.

Comment: if you mean a async replication the there are the same write on the slave as on the Master. is it not importend to have the results in realtime you can create a new table where you only stores the new opt and add them frequently. is much faster. you also can play with the doubble write buffer to speed up 100%. and you can change the time when innodb write back to disc. if you do this it is possible that you loos a few seconds of data when the database chrashes

Comment: I think I was wrong, I mixed things up with a different problem I had recently. Bernd is right, MyISAM won't help, you most probably would probably get table locks all the time.

Comment: @BerndBuffen I like your idea to create a new table to only store the new opt. So basically instead of using update all the time, I do an insert to store the vote, and then frequently update the poll votes count by using a count on the number of rows inserted?

Comment: i will write my answer tomorrow. i have no time in moment

Comment: @BerndBuffen could you write your answer? It would help me a lot. Thank you again

Comment: @Patrick - is it possible that we chat or phone to find a good solution for your problem. There are many change you can do, but some can be difficult , impossible or to much work with your software. my phonenumber is in my profile. I hope that my english is good for you